# Best sample rate AAC 5.1 384Kbits?

Tags: ffmpeg, aac

I have a movie with AC3 5.1 audio with 48khz of sample rate and change to AAC using libfdk_aac codec. I don't know if use the same sample rate or set to 44.1khz. In the libfdk_aac [documentation the recomendation](https://wiki.hydrogenaud.io/index.php?title=Fraunhofer_FDK_AAC#Recommended_Sampling_Rate_and_Bitrate_Combinations) for 5.1 is use 44.1khz. It's a bad idea set the same rate or is better chage to 44.1khz?

Comment: If you don't have to change the sample rate then you should just copy the stream as is.  [Generation loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss) is a thing and while you may not notice *much* difference between the two sample rates you *are* changing the data and potentially introducing aliasing artefacts that could, given a couple more conversions, become significant. When converting audio or video you should prefer to always convert from your original source.

Comment: The problem is that i don't know why, but if not set the sample rate, it changes to 96 khz and in my tv the sound has "artifacts", i have to use a sound bar. I am trying options

Comment: Is there no passthrough or copy mode in your application? If you are using ffmpeg then you may be able to use the ["copy" codec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567029/ffmpeg-to-duplicate-an-audio-stream-and-encode-this-new-stream) which will, as the name suggests, simply copy audio streams without conversion:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

20 years ago I'd have said stick to 48KHz, as the algorithms weren't as good.

These days, 48 for 'video' & 44.1 for 'CD audio' conventions are really just that - conventions.

You are extremely unlikely to be able to hear the difference. Not only would your ears still need to be good up to 22KHz [which is extremely unlikely by the time you reach 20 years old] but your playback equipment would need to be that good too.

In short, though I doubt you'll really save much disk space by doing it, you may as well, as no-one will be able to tell the difference.

Comment: Thanks, I never change the sample rate but now if not set it, it changes to 96khz and not sound good in my tv and is the only difference between other files.

Comment: That changes the entire direction of your question, making it & this answer no longer reflective of your actual issue. You need to ask the question you need the answer to, not one that's merely an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

If you are using Fraunhofer FDK AAC use:

- Object type AAC-LC (libfdk_aac)
- Constant bit rate
- Bit rate of 512 kbps
- 48 kHz

For example:

```
ffmpeg -i INPUT -vn -c:a libfdk_aac -cutoff 20000 -b:a 512k OUTPUT
```

For a 2 h 30 min film with a 6 channel DTS-HD track that would give you an approximately a 500 MB audio file. 48.0 kHz is the default unless you change it.

First of all, you are confusing the [sampling rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_(signal_processing)) with the [bit rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_rate).

### Sample rate

While the [Nyquist theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem) suggests that a sample rate of 44.1 kHz is enough for the human hearing range, 48 kHz is the de facto standard in audio for video. I would always stick to that to avoid playback compatibility issues, at leas for audio in video files. Theoretically, there is no reason 48 kHz is better sounding, it has just become a standard over the years.

You can use a sample rate of up to 96 kHz with AAC, but it will not make the audio sound any better. In fact, it will not add any quality whatsoever. If you are concerned about the audio quality you should keep the AC3 or at least convert it to a [lossless format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_compression#Audio).

The [bit depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audio_bit_depth) and [bit rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_rate#Audio) is a lot more important to the perceived audio quality.

### Bit rate

If you really want to degrade the audio quality by converting it to a *lossy* format such as AAC, but you still want the best subjectively audible quality, you should just go for the highest available bit rate unless you have any specific reasons not to.

[This](https://listening-test.coresv.net/results.htm) test suggests using AAC with 96 kbps in order to match or outmatch the perceived quality of MP3 at 128 kbps. However, this bit rate is quite low by today's standards.

FFMpeg [suggests](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC) using 64 kbps for each channel in the stream. So for a stereo track that would be 128 kbps. I am not sure what this conclusion is based on, but I believe this is reasonable.

I would personally just max it out to 512 kbps just to be safe. It is not going to take much space anyway since the file will be lossy and in terms of bandwidth, it will constitute a very little overall.

However, this all depends on your use case and it is impossible to give an exact number unless you have any specific limitations.